# how to animate BottomNavigationBar like in the image?

Tags: android, android-animation, bottomnavigationview

I am having a task to complete the on `BottomNavigationBar`. The task is when user click on second element in the `BottomNavigationBar`, user should move from first element to second element with animation or if user click on third element user should move from first element to third element with animation.
*(just like in savan application)*

please see the gif for more clarity

[image: BottomNavigationBar with animation]

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty of animation options using the Android native animations API. All you need to do is hook it on the change event correctly. Below is a sample animation implementation

```
 private static final int ANIMATED_ITEMS_COUNT = 2;
 private void runEnterAnimation(View view, int position) {
          if (position >= ANIMATED_ITEMS_COUNT - 1) {
               return;
           }
          if (position > lastAnimatedPosition) {
             lastAnimatedPosition = position;
             Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_out);
             view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my app bottomnavigation is created with activities only there are no fragments. I undersand how to apply these to my activities. can you please tell me about how to do this with 2 activities

Comment: With different activities you mean you have the bottom bar in both activities? If so then just add the animation you need within `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);` 
Replace the animations with any animation you need. Put in within the startActivity body.

Comment: animation is `slide-from-left` to `side-to-right` I don't think `overridePendingTransition` is going to work. because if you u r second element and if you click on first one how to apply different animation?

Comment: You can apply virtually any animation.. the `fade-in` and `fade-out` are custom animations within my project.